# What settings does Sprint Gingerbread (2.3) update reset?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, settings, updates, htc-evo

After installing the Gingerbread upgrade on my EVO, I noticed that my alarms have been reset.  Now I'm wondering what, if any, other settings were reset or changed.

I have not been able an official list anywhere.

Which settings get changed or reset with the Sprint Gingerbread update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there really shouldn't be any other settings which are affected by the OTA. In fact, Android Central [has a thread](http://forum.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g/90457-gingerbread-update-bugs-new-apps-etc.html) where people are compiling a list of new features and apps along with reported issues and bugs. They've put this (losing your alarms) in their list of bugs. It looks like it also broke Netflix and Wireless-N support, for what it's worth.

Comment: It also appears that some form of fiddling with the app will allow them to render again.  Not sure if it's close/open or change tabs, but I've seen them disappear and re-appear after being re-created after upgrade.